# MySQL database dump import order (schema, routines, triggers, events and data)

Tags: mysql

I use a bash script that dumps separate areas of a single database to separate dump files. Currently the files are dumped in this order:

1. Database, table and view schema.
2. Routines.
3. Triggers.
4. Events.
5. Data.

Now, I was wondering - **in what order should I import the data if I were to?**

I have one concern if I were to import the dumps in the same order - if I import triggers before importing data, will they be "triggered" during import?

Should I import schema first, then data and then the rest? Is there any particular order I should be doing this?

Comment: The suggested order provided by mysqldump is correct and you should follow the same order too. Triggers will triggered during import unless you explicitly skip the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer myself in case anyone needs to know explicitly.

As @ajreal [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131282/mysql-database-dump-import-order-schema-routines-triggers-events-and-data#comment11476413_9131282), the best way would be follow the order mysqldump outputs. And mysqldump's order is as follows:

1. Database
2. Tables

   1. Table schema (inc. constraints)
   2. Table data
   3. Table triggers
3. Views - temporary tables only!
4. Events.
5. Routines.
6. Views - final view structure

Comment: +1 But one other nuance is to delay creation of secondary indexes until after data has been loaded, to speed up data load and take advantage of fast index creation.  This feature has been added to mysqldump in Percona Server.